# How to create a xamarin forms cross platform hamburger slide view

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am coding a xamarin forms android and ios cross-platform app. I would like to add it so when you push a button it creates a hamburger slideout navigation menu with buttons that navigate to another page. I tried watching tutorials but none of them explained it well enough for me to be able to create since I am fairly new to xamarin.

I tried following this tutorial [here](http://adrianszen.com/2017/03/22/how-to-implement-hamburger-menu-in-xamarin-forms/), but I don't get it since I already have a main page I called "MainPage" and two pages called "SearchPage" and "ProfilePage" so the naming confuses me since they have other pages and stuff and get lost.

Comment: There is a very good and simple official guide. Did you check it? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page/

Comment: @EvZ When I try to create the MainPageCS page the "Master = MasterPage;" line says the name Master does not exist in the current context

Comment: @Jacob You should create your own MasterPage, and put your detail pages in it as MasterPageItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically, you have a MasterDetailPage that is both the "Slide View" (it's called `Drawer` on Android and `Master` on Xamarin.Forms) and the ContentView (it's called `Detail` on Xamarin.Forms). Each of these views is a Page on Xamarin.

You can create a MasterDetailPage just by setting these two proprieties (Master and Detail) to a Page, like this:

```
// MainPage here is the Propriety of the App class that controls the current displayed page
MainPage = new MasterDetailPage
{
    Master = new ContentPage { Content = new StackLayout { Children = { new Label { Text = "This is the Drawer Page!" } } } },
    Detail = new ContentPage { Content = new StackLayout { Children = { new Label { Text = "This is the Detail Page!" } } } }
};
```

Add this to your App class and you'll have a Drawer that says `"This is the Drawer Page!"` and a Detail Page that says `"This is the Detail Page!"`.

Now, if you separate those ContentPages in classes, would be something like this:

```
public class MasterPage : ContentPage
{
    public MasterPage()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                new Label { Text = "This is the Master page!" }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class DetailPage : ContentPage
{
    public DetailPage()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                new Label { Text = "This is the Detail page!" }
            }
        }
    }
}

// And in the App constructor
MainPage = new MasterDetailPage
{
    Master = new MasterPage(),
    Detail = new DetailPage()
};
```

And that's it... If you have any more question about this feel free to ask :)

---

Edit after comment

This code is meant to use in the App class, other classes don't have the `MainPage` property.

If you want your MainPage class to be a `MasterDetailPage` you could just extend `MainPage` from `MasterDetailPage` (`public class MainPage : MasterDetailPage`) and, after the login, instead of pushing it with Navigation, set App's `MainPage` to your MainPage by calling:

```
App.Current.MainPage = new MainPage 
{ 
    Master = MasterPage(), 
    Detail = DetailPage() 
};
```

Comment: When my app starts it navigates to a login page then to a class I have called "MainPage" I tried adding the top code to my MainPage constructor but it gives an error.

Comment: I'm still confused exactly how to implement this, I have only ever used NavigationPages and new to Xamarin. I have to create a class called MasterPageDetail with what in it? Right now I have it when the App constructor is ran it checks if there is already login data if so creates a NavigationPage to MainPage else goes to LoginPage (after logging in LoginPage goes to MainPage) I want the MainPage to have the drawer with options for "Home" (aka MainPage) and "Search" to the SearchPage

Comment: Try to understand what I said. The MasterDetailPage has a property for the Drawer and a property for the Content. The type of both properties is Page. Just set the `Master` property of MasterDetailPage to a `Page` that represents your Drawer (Slide-View) and set the Detail property to a Page that represents the Content (usually a NavigationPage with a ContentPage inside it)

Comment: I get it now, thanks a lot for your help! Works perfectly!